# Find if all characters in one string occur within another string

Tags: string, bash, if-statement

I am new to `bash`. I have a question about determining if all characters of one string occur within another string. For example, if the variables are:

```bash
var_1="abcdefg"
var_2="bcg"
```

Then I want to write an `if` statement of the form:

```bash
if [all characters of var_2 occur within var_1]
then
     echo "All characters of var_2 occur in var_1."
else
     echo "Not all characters of var_2 occur in var_1."
fi
```

In this example, the output should be `All characters of var_2 occur in var_1.` What would go in the `if` statement here?

This is what I tried:

```bash
if [[ $var_1 == *$var_2* ]]
```

... but I think this is only determines if `var_2` is a substring of `var_1`. What I want is to determine if the characters of `var_2` occur within `var_1` in no particular order.

Answer (score 2):

The following oneliner should work:

```bash
echo -e "$var_2\0$var_1" | sed -E ':a;s/(.)(.*\x0)(.*)\1(.*)/\2\3\4/;ta;s/^\x0.*/1/;s/.*\x0.*/0/'
```

It will print `0` or `1` to mean *false* or *true* respectively.

This is how it works:

- `echo -e` allows using escape sequences, and `\0` represents the null character, which I'm using to mark the separation between the two strings `bcg` and `abcdefg`.
- The Sed script is not that complex:

  - `-E` is a non POSIX option allowing to use `(` and `)` instead of `\(` and `\)` to write capturing groups (and other similar simplifications which I'm not using here);
  - `;`s separate commands;
  - `:a` is a label, and allows one jumping here via `ta` or `ba` (I use only the former, keep reading);
  - `s/(.)(.*\x0)(.*)\1(.*)/\2\3\4/` does the following (which succeedes if there's at least one character in common between `var_2` and `var_1`):

    - matches and captures the first character of `var_2` with `(.)`,
    - matches and captures the following part of `var_2` together with the null character, `(.*\x0)` (yes, what you write as `\0` in Bash is `\x0` in Sed),
    - matches and captures 0 or more characters,
    - matches what was captured by first group, i.e. by `(.)`,
    - matches and captures 0 or more characters up to the end of `var_1`,
    - substitutes all that was matched with what was captured by the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th capturing groups: in fact, we've got rid of one character in common between `var_2` and `var_1`;
  - `ta` test if the previous `s`ubstitution was successful and, if that's the case, it jumps to `:a`: this way we are running a loop as long as there's a characters in common between `var_2` and `var_1`;
  - when ther's no characters in common between `var_2` and `var_1`, the test will fail, and the control will fall through `ta`;
  - `s/^\x0.*/1/` matches whatever is left, but only if the null character `\x0` is leading, which happens if all letters of `var_2` were found in `var_1`, and changes everything to just `1`;
  - `s/.*\x0.*/0/` will match everything, as long as there's still `\x0` in the string, which happens only if the previous substitution failed, which means that some letter from `var_2` was *not* found in `var_1`, and change it to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple method in pure `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

var_1="abcdefg"
var_2="bcg"

if [[ ${var_2//["$var_1"]} ]]; then
    echo "Not all characters of var_2 occur in var_1."
else
    echo "All characters of var_2 occur in var_1."
fi
```

The `${var_2//[$var_1]}` expands to the value of `var_2` with all characters that occur in `var_1` deleted. All characters of `var_2` occur in `var_1` only if that expansion is null string.

Comment: This appears to work and is elegant. I want to make sure I understand what's going on here though... the // operator replaces all instances of the elements of var_1 (written as an array [$var_1] ) within var_2 with the null string. So if any elements of var_2 do not exist in var_1, that will be output and since its not equal to the null string, the "else" section is activated. Is this accurate?

Comment: @cheddarblake Roughly correct. For more information, you may read [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), the paragraph starting with **${parameter/pattern/string}**. Specially the sentence "If _string_ is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the ‘/’ following _pattern_ may be omitted."

Comment: @cheddarblake But `[$var_1]` is not an array at all. It is a bracket expression used in pattern matching. See [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

Comment: Nice trick +1. And if you use double-quotes `[[ ${var_2//["$var_1"]} ]]` then it handles correctly any arbitrary sequence of characters!!!

Answer (score 1):

Not really an `if` clause/statement, something like.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

i=0
var_2="bcg"
var_1="abcdefg"
total_str=${#var_2}

while (( i < total_str )); do
  [[ $var_1 = *"${var_2:i++:1}"* ]] || {
    printf >&2 'Not all characters of the string "%s" occur in the string "%s".\n' "$var_2" "$var_1"
    exit 1
  }
done

printf 'All characters of the string "%s" occur in the string "%s".\n' "$var_2" "$var_1"
```

Output

```
All characters of the string "bcg" occur in the string "abcdefg".
```

---

Changing the value of `var_2` to something like

```
var_2="bxg"
```

The output should be:

```
Not all characters of the string "bxg" occur in the string "abcdefg".
```